# Is using macro's to allocate memory bad?

Tags: c, memory-management, macros

I want to use something like this to allocate memory:

```
void* pointers = NULL;
#define MALLOC(size) ({\
    void* ptr = malloc(size);
    ARRAYAPPEND(pointers, ptr);\
})
#define FREE(ptr) ({\
    ARRAYREMOVEBYVALUE(pointers, ptr);\
    free(ptr);\
})
#define FREEALL() ({\
    FREEARRAY(pointers);\
})
```

`ARRAYAPPEND` will add a item to a array, or create a array with the item in it when it points to `NULL`

`ARRAYREMOVEBYVALUE` will `free()` all items from a array that have a matching value. If all values in the array match, it will free the whole array using `FREEARRAY()`. With `ARRAYREMOVEBYEXPRESSION`, things like `strcmp(value, "")` would also work. (Not that I would need to use it)

`ARRAYSIZE` will return the size of a array, or 0 when it points to `NULL`

`FREEARRAY` will free all pointers in a array, and free the array itself after that. If the array points to `NULL`, no actions will be taken.

Of course I will also support `realloc` and `calloc`.

Is this a good way to allocate and deallocate memory, is there a library that has a safer way of doing this (I am creating these macro's from scratch), should I `free()` every single memory adress manualy, or should I rely on use the unsafe but working automatic cleanup by the OS? (Currently, support for Windows 8 only is totaly fine, and Windows 8 has automatic cleanup)? My goal is to free all memory on program exit, and obviously not runtime

(I can find out myself that

```
while (1) {
    malloc(10000);
}
```

will eventurely run out of memory, but my question is if this:

```
char* x = MALLOC(10000);
FREEALL();
```

is safer than relying on OS cleanup, and if this:

```
char* x = malloc(10000);
free(x);
```

is prefered above using macro's. Maybe there are hidden calls to `malloc` that I cant control? In these cases, there is no real reason for using macro's, but for example for

```
while (strcmp(SUBSTRING(str, 0, 14), "Hello, world!") {
    // Code (No cleanup)
})
```

there might be hidden calls to `malloc` inside SUBSTRING (For example for creating a new string) that won't be `free`'d. Should I use macro's in this case:

```
SESSION_SET("SESSION1");
while (strcmp(SUBSTRING(str, 0, 14), "Hello, world!") {
    // Code (No cleanup)
})
SESSION_FREE("SESSION1");
```

or will relying on automatic cleanup be good enough?)

My problem is basicaly: I want to allocate memory without saving its adress, should I force myself to save every adress and `free()` it manualy, should I use macro's, is there any library that does this for me, or should I rely on OS cleanup?

Reaction to @wildplasser s comment:
A macro IS a inline function... :| (EDIT: Okay... Maybe a macro doesn't check types. But thats it.) Also I prefer to type
`char* item = MALLOC(10);FREEALL();` above typing

```
void* array = NULL; // Array of pointers
char* item = malloc(10); // Allocate item
int size = (array == NULL ? 0 : sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])); // Get length of array
array = realloc(array, (size + 1) * sizeof(item)); // Reallocate array
array[size] = item; // Add item to new array
size = (array == NULL ? 0 : sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])); // Get new size of array (Wow, a macro would be usefull, wouldn't it?)
int i = 0; // Lets loop over all the items
while (i < size) { // In our array of pointers
    free(array[i]); // And free all those pointers
}
free(array); // Lets free the array too...
array = NULL; // What did we end up doing? Nothing!
```

Comment: nobody in C has automatic cleanup other than via exiting the process. If you want a way to ensure things are cleaned up when you leave scope you'll either need to use C++ with RAII or a garbage collected language.

Comment: Why macros rather than functions?

Comment: *Windows 8 has automatic cleanup* Do you have a source for that claim!?!?

Comment: Dynamic memory is only freed when the process exits and never automatically before.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, in fact, try executing a program allocating 10000 items a few million times.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY it seems you are confusing process teardown with freeing memory during execution. One is something that happens when the OS destroys the process, the other is a way of ensuring you can reuse memory during execution.

Comment: @black: Yes, but is it reliable? Thats the whole point of declaring these macro's. Oliver Charlesworth: This has nothing to do with scope, I just want to know if these macro's are safe enough for exiting the program. I will update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY yes....it is 100% reliable if the compiler obeys the standard.

Comment: @DonLarynx not the compiler. The OS, this has nothing to do with the standard. Merely the OS destroying a virtual address space and thus making the pages invalid and the ranges marked for zeroing.

Comment: I updated the question: I want to make sure all memory is `free()`'d when the program exits, how would I do this?

Comment: @YoYoYonnY all the memory will be freed when the program exits anyway. if you don't care about memory management during execution then there isn't much to do.

Comment: The macros are not needed. Static *inline* functions will do exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry Oliver Charlesworth I ment @Mgetz. Mgetz, Using functions is totally redundant in this case, I just want to save all allocated pointers somewhere. (More specificly: I want to make sure all allocated memory is free'd when the program ends, and possibly in other cases aswell) However, doing this manually is a pain, and using macro's might not be totally safe. Moreover, functions will add a couple of items to the stack, which might eventually cause a stack overflow (Really, 12 bytes or so wont be a problem, but still its redundant)

Comment: @wildplasser I want to put all I want to say in a comment but that wont work let me edit the question.

Comment: In C99 or better you should prefer `inline` functions to such macros.

Comment: I guess using inline won't give me any problems, my only problem with inline at the moment is that I want my functions to be uppercase. (Yes, thats a problem to me) `inline void* MALLOC(int size);` doesnt look as good to me, but I'll probably never end up looking at it anyway, so I guess `inline` is the way to go

Comment: If you want uppercase, you could use the capslock.

Comment: @wildplasser But then I would have to press shift everytime I don't want to type in uppercase. What I was trying to say is I use uppercase only for macro's, because otherwise it doesn't look like C to me. But I never had to use inline, so I might just as well use uppercase for inline aswell.

Comment: The CAPITALS-ONLY for macro names is only a (good) convention. The lurking problem with macros is side-effects. Inlined functions don't have that problem and (should) behave just like ordinary function calls.

Comment: Yet still, will inline functions be safe enough? I dont want to create a whole header with inline functions redefining `*alloc` functions to then find out that other functions implicitly use malloc aswell... Also, from what I've read, inline is just #define FUNC() ({}) with type checking. Ill try out inline on gcc C89 and C99

Comment: @YoYoYonnY the problem with what you want to do is that even if you can get it to work (dangerous, probably will cause unintended side effects) then you are making the code incredibly fragile. Because anyone can `#undef MALLOC` and your code breaks. Include a library that does that... and your code breaks etc. `inline` functions are less fragile because they can't be `#undef` but still have the issue of being copied everywhere, which can also have unexpected side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mgetz, I didn't yet think about `#undef`. You convinded me to use `inline`. Anyway, I dont want to force other people to use `MALLOC` (From my header) above `malloc` (from `stdlib.h`), I just want to make sure *my* code `free()`s all allocated memory blocks when the program ends

Comment: Acturely, I do want all the code to use MALLOC, but the question still is: Is there any other way to allocate memory besides `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`? And is there any other way to `free` memory besides from the function and the OS cleanup?

Answer (score 2):

All your work here is essentially useless: it's faulty and doesn't achieve its purpose.

*Any* memory a program allocates will be returned back to the OS after it ends. This applies to all operating systems that use virtual memory - think any 32-bit or 64-bit modern OS (modern here means "made in this century"). *If the OS doesn't do this (or if there is no OS), you would already know it.*

Therefore all the problems with freeing memory apply when your program is still running.

The way you allocate memory only applies to these translation units where you define the macro. The moment you will use external library (and you will, eventually), you will be back to square one:

```
// this is a function that creates a texture (for drawing to screen). IT'S ENTIRELY OUT OF YOUR CONTROL.
SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTexture(SDL_Renderer* renderer,
                               Uint32        format,
                               int           access, 
                               int           w,
                               int           h);

// somewhere in your code
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, 128, 64);
// now what
```

Comment: This is a answer I was looking for. I didn't think about external libraries relying on OS cleaning techniques/manualy saving pointers. Ill probably still use `MALLOC` functions for my code, because I am working on a interpreter and want to implement a garbage collector, and I cant always manualy save the memory pointers because its not how the interpreter works (That way I would have to define 1000+ pointers), but otherwise you're right: Defining macro's for allocating memory is kind of useless. In my case, defining a custom methods will be worth it but I doubt I'll ever use it after this.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Not sure if that's the correct conclusion. While you can rely on the OS that will get back the memory, *you must close the program first*. This means for long running programs, you have to free the memory manually anyway - you can't simply leak it. The problem with your approach is that it can't be generalized to handle any library. You need to create more complex scheme - [see this document about garbage collection strategies](http://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse40243/spring2006/gc-survey.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the document, I'll read through it. I guess `#define` is the only way to achive what I want, since C doesn't allow `void*` to be dereferenced. (And thus, I cant use `inline void* MALLOC(int ptr);`) I'll create private `*ALLOC` functions so I won't have to declare and free every single variable myself. I think `MEMORY_SESSION("Name")` will be the perfect solution for simulating multiple scopes (So I can allow multiple files to be interpreted at once). EDIT: I cant think. If `inline` doesn't work then `#define` wont work either...